# copying and pasting information between datasets

Tags: mainframe

How to copy data fully from one dataset to another dataset when one of the dataset consists of dots as shown bllow ?

[image]

Comment: please be more precise, show your first and second datasets

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using JCL?

Comment: suppose my PS dataset consists of 1000 rows like ..838   ......1112(format) so because of these dots i am unable to move 1112 to left side.so what i was doing is i was copying some some 20rows and i am pasting it to another dataset. so that i am able to move data in the new dataset.it is time consuming process.while i was trying to give cut and paste to another dataset i am unable to move data again in new dataset.while copying some 15 rows only i am able to move data.so i need at a time copying all rows so that i am able to move data to particular columns.

Comment: Are you the same person who asked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56337187/mainframe-commands-for-ds-move-columns-in-ispf-edit?

Comment: Also, as I put in my answer below, those aren't dots.  That is data that isn't displayable in whatever character set you're using, so you're losing data by making the edits you're making.  I'd very strongly suggest talking to your system programmer about what utilities are available.  And possibly asking a different question that actually explains what you're trying to do and why.

Comment: As a employee of IBM you are not allowed to ask questions on a public forum. You have the entire resources of IBM world-wide to assist you.

Answer (score 3):

The dots you are seeing are most likely undisplayable data so a utility is the best bet.

There are many ways to move data around on z/OS.  If you are simply trying to copy an existing dataset to another to make a copy you could use a batch utility like `IEBGENER`.  Here is some sample JCL

```
//IEBGENER JOB (CCCCCCCC),'HOGSTROM',                               
//             MSGLEVEL=(1,1),                                      
//             MSGCLASS=O,                                          
//             CLASS=A,                                             
//             NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                       
//*                                                                 
//*----------------------------------------------------------       
//*       IEBGENER                                                  
//*----------------------------------------------------------       
//GENER02  EXEC PGM=IEBGENER                                        
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*                                             
//SYSUT1   DD  DSN=USER1.TEST.DATA,DISP=SHR                         
//SYSUT2   DD  DSN=USER1.TEST.ODATA,DISP=(,CATLG,DELETE),           
//             UNIT=SYSDA,SPACE=(CYL,5,RLSE),DCB=USER1.TEST.DATA    
//SYSIN    DD  DUMMY                                                
//
```

You could also use online tools like ISPF Option 3.2 to create the new dataset

[image]

and 3.3 to move / copy it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what question you're asking, or why you'd do such a thing by hand.  I'd instead suggest using one of the built in z/OS tools.  Specifically, IEBCOPY.

```
//COPYLIKE JOB MSGCLASS=H,TIME=1440                              
//COPYREP  EXEC PGM=IEBCOPY                                      
//SYSPRINT DD SYSOUT=*                                           
//SYSUT1   DD DSN=SYS1.LPALIB,DISP=SHR,UNIT=3390,VOL=SER=D83RL2  
//SYSUT2   DD DSN=SYS1.LPALIB.ORIG,                              
//        LIKE=SYS1.LPALIB,                                      
//        DISP=(NEW,KEEP),VOL=SER=D83RL2,UNIT=3390               
//SYSIN    DD *                                                  
/*
```

Also, as a note, the source dataset doesn't consist of dots, it consists of undisplayable data.